# Header length shorter than required width with scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrbook

MWE is given below. And picture later. Cannot use scrbook because then the header style changes and screws up differently. Don't mind a working example with page number on one side and the sectionmark on the other if you get it to work with scrbook though, since it measures the length right. Tried different options for headwidth already. None gave correct.

```
\documentclass[letter, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[nouppercase,headsepline,headwidth=text]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoption{headsepline}{.75pt:\textwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage[margin=1.1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Blaaaaaaaa}
    \section{BlaaaaaaaaBlaaaaaaaaBlaaaaaaaa}
    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you set your textwidth with `geometry` you have to set your KOMAoptions after loading that.

[image: koma]

```
\documentclass[letter, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[nouppercase,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage[margin=1.1in]{geometry}
\KOMAoption{headsepline}{.75pt:\textwidth}
\KOMAoption{headwidth}{text}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Blaaaaaaaa}
    \section{BlaaaaaaaaBlaaaaaaaaBlaaaaaaaa}
    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah that worked like a charm. I guess I will have to be more careful with the KOMA classes/packages. Thanks :)